# PHP server side post

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am trying to get a server side POST to work in PHP. I am trying to send transaction data to a payment gateway but I keep getting the following error:

> Message: `fopen(https://secure.ogone.com/ncol/test/orderstandard.asp)`: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required

Code:

```
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8',
        'method' => "POST",
        'header' => "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
        "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
     )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$fp = fopen('https://secure.ogone.com/ncol/test/orderstandard.asp', 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

Tried a few solutions found online - mostly shots in the dark so no luck so far!

Comment: I think the error means that you have to include `Content-length` header.  Compute the number of bytes in your submitted data and include this header.

Comment: Thanks for your response - is the best way to do this to write the message to a file, get the file size and use this value???

Comment: Where is your POST data?

Comment: I have not yet tried posting it - I was just looking to get a basic post working first; which should return an XML file from oGone with the error (values missing!) in it.

Comment: You can do that - or you can just compute it all in memory without writing to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add content length. Once you actually start sending content you’ll need to calculate its length.

```
$data = "";
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8',
        'method' => "POST",
        'header' => "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
        "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n" .
        'Content-length: '. strlen($data) . "\r\n",
        'content' => $data
     )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$fp = fopen('https://secure.ogone.com/ncol/test/orderstandard.asp', 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this request to force the browser to show the page thats been posted to??

Comment: What browser? Doesn’t fpassthru() dump the content of the POST request to stdout?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `content` option and your code should work. There is no need to specify `Content-length`, PHP will calculate it for you:

```
$opts = array(
    "http" => array(
        "method" => "POST",
        "header" =>
            "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
            "Cookie: foo=bar",
        "content" => http_build_query(array(
            "foo" => "bar",
            "bla" => "baz"
        ))
    )
);
```

Notes:

- In the above example, the server receives `Content-length: 15` header even though it is not explicitly specified.
- Content-type for POST data is usually `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: According to the RFC http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html The content-length field "SHOULD be sent whenever the message's length can be determined prior to being transferred". So if you can calculate it, then send it.

Comment: Yes. PHP will calculate it for you by looking at the content.